# How can I install a specific version of socketio 4.4.0?

Tags: python, python-socketio

I have some issues with fxcm packages and I need to install python-socketio **4.4.0**. However, pip cannot this version.

```
    (base) C:\Users\murth>pip uninstall python-socketio
Found existing installation: python-socketio 5.0.4
Uninstalling python-socketio-5.0.4:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\murth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\python_socketio-5.0.4.dist-info\*
    c:\users\murth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\socketio\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled python-socketio-5.0.4

(base) C:\Users\mur>**pip install python-socketio 4.4.0**
Collecting python-socketio
  Downloading python_socketio-5.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 52 kB 337 kB/s
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 4.4.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 4.4.0

(base) C:\Users\mur>
```

Answer (score 2):

pip install python-socketio==4.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The == operator is used to specify the version wanted, like the follow sintax:

```
pip install module==module_version
```

So, what you want is:

```
pip install python-socketio==4.4.0
```